# Not able to convert python variable in .sql file in aws repo

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, variables, yaml, config

there is a variable which reads the file from s3 and this s3 file has sql select statement.

select * from {schema_name}.{table_name};

now schema_name and table_name is defined in variable.yml file. but these varaibles are only accessible if i store this sql statement in sql folder of my project.
and call that sql file in glue.yml file which creates glue job.

is there a way to store this sql statement in in sql file at runtime ?

i tried to create a file at runtime in sql folder. but it is not creating.
because i am not sure how i open that file.

Comment: You can use the **boto3** library to access the S3 service and read the file containing the SQL statement from S3.

Alternatively, you can use the **pandas** library to read the file from S3 directly into a DataFrame and then execute the SQL statement using the pandasql library

Comment: i am able to read. but it is giving error - schema_name is not defined. however i have defined schema name in config file. 
the config file works fine if i have a .sql file in vs code folder. but in this case, I have sql inside a variable. so schema_name is not getting populated. 

example if i have a .sql file -

select * from college.student

example if i am reading sql in variable - 
select * from {schema_name}.{table_name};

so in second case my paramters are not geeting replaced by the values